# Blender crashing when opening files

Tags: modeling

I recently installed Blender 3.2.1, and immediately I noticed that, when opening previously created files Blender crashes, no error messages or anything - just gone. I rolled back to 3.1 and had the same problem (previously worked ok), I've now tried 3.3 alpha as well and I get the same result. This happens on almost all files - I've noticed that SOME of the autosave.blend files will open OK.

the link below is just a basic stage that I use, with a background, couple of lights and a camera - even that crashes.

[Basic Stage.blend](https://pointzerocomau.sharepoint.com/:u:/s/PointZero/EeakDkk-VfhKmZqJ8K0nNwYBg2-h03kZ_hsN5BNkibXmaQ?e=D0gecu)

EDIT: I just noticed that if I try to open a file it will crash - if I try the same file again immediately it will (maybe?) work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please don't post external links to blend files. You can upload your file to https://pasteall.org/blend/ or https://blend-exchange.com/help as long as you paste the link to it into your question. I've looked at your file with Blender 3.2.1 and it loads fine, but the camera Clip Start is set to such a low value that it's causing flickering in the viewport when you try to move the cylinder.

Comment: It causes flickering and also makes the navigation controls go nuts. The clip end is also one zero too much. It also probably doesn't help that your objects are big, like your cylinder 50 meters high and 100 meters long/large. I guess you change your clip values at some point because you had some display issues maybe, but instead you should check your object's scales before changing these.

Comment: Hi :). Works just fine here, Blender 3.2.

Comment: Thanks for the general tips.
I'm now suspicious of a registry problem. I have a similar issue with a different program that needs to update the registry when opening if changing versions. That program freezes without crashing, but a second launch works for that program too.